# Partial view to main view ? MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement to create multiple partial view and use them in main view .

Well i created my partial set of views sucessfully and in my main view i am unable to access the ID's of the controls in main view .

I used this to consume my partial view in main view   **@html.renderpartial("partialviewname")**

PARTIAL VIEW :

```
<div id="dvphonelogactivity">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <input type="text" id="txtdate"  />
            </td>
             <td>
              <select id="searchlist" name="searchlist">
       <option value="0">Inbound</option>
                  <option value="1">Outbound</option>
</select> 

            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Stackholders:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtStack" /></td>




        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Details/Notes:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtDetails"  /></td>



        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" title="Log" value="Log" id="submit" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

MAIN VIEW CODE :

```
 <div class="tab_container"> 

                 <div id="phone" style="display: none;" class="tab_content">
                @Html.Partial("Meeting")
            </div>

            <div id="meeting" style="display: none;" class="tab_content">
                @Html.Partial("Meeting")
            </div>


               <div id="mailing" style="display: none;" class="tab_content" >
                   @Html.Partial("Mail")
           </div>


            <div id="divnote" style="display: none;" class="tab_content">
                 @Html.Partial("Notes")

            </div>
                </div>    

             <input type="button" title="Log" value="Log" id="submit" />
        </body>
```

In main view script file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtDate").datetimepicker();

                    $("#submit").click(function () {
                        debugger;
                        var date = $("#txtdate").val();
                        var search = $("#searchlist").val();
                        var stack = $("#txtStack").val();
                        var details = $("#txtDetails").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/Lead",
                            type: "Post",
                            data: JSON.stringify([date, search, stack, details]),
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            success: function (data) { },
                            error: function () { alert('error'); }
                        });
                    });
```

So how to consume partial views controls id and get the value so i can send to value controller and do write logic to store in DB .

Regards

Comment: post some view code,,

Comment: you want to render partial view in main view?? question is not very clear?

Comment: yes mate . let me give my partial view and main view code ..

Comment: partial views not rendering?

Comment: in my script file i written like $("#txtdate").val(); in this how to access txtdate which is present in partialview & in shared folder

Comment: same way the way you doing

Comment: well values are coming into var date ? just now checked but i am getting JSON UNDEFINED ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of your document (and of course remove any other doctype you might have).

Also you should use:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you only need to support **IE10**. If you need to use earlier versions of IE (some people still need to support IE6) you can use the JS implementation of JSON:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

and one more thing:

You should use **Jquery 1.9** version only for IE 6,7,8

Comment: im using Jquery 1.9.1 version and my ie version is 8

Comment: gald that it helped you.